# traefik 502 bad gateway after a certain time

Tags: docker, nginx, uwsgi, traefik, bad-gateway

## Problem

I'm running traefik to serve a python django app inside an docker container. The app is running without problems over https or http. After a unspecific time (under an hour) traefik logs says "*502 Bad Gateway*" and my nginx and uwsgi logs dont say anything. "docker restart djangoapp" fixed the Problem for a short time.

## Setup

Internet -> traefik -> nginx -> uwsgi -> djangoapp

### traefik.toml

```
debug = true

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# Access log
[traefikLog]
  filePath = "/var/log/traefik/traefik.log"
  format = "json"

[accessLog]
  filePath = "/var/log/traefik/access.log"
  format = "json"

[web]
address = ":8080"
        [web.auth.basic]
        users = ["admin:XXX/"]

[entryPoints]
        [entryPoints.http]
          address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.https]
          address = ":443"
          [entryPoints.https.tls]
            [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
            certFile = "/etc/ssl/traefik/cert-register.stupa.pem"
            keyFile = "/etc/ssl/traefik/key-register.stupa.key"
```

### docker-compose.yml traefik

```
version: '2'

services:
  frontproxy:
    image: traefik
    container_name: frontproxy
    command: --api --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /srv/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/traefik
      - /srv/frontproxy/logs:/var/log/traefik

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: frontproxy
```

### docker-compose djangoapp

```
version: '3'

networks:
    helfertoolnet:
    frontproxy:
      external: true

volumes:
  postgresVolume:

services:
  helfertool_app:
     image: helfertool
     hostname: helfertool_app
     command: [/usr/bin/supervisord]
     container_name: helfertool_app
     volumes:
       - /srv/helfertool/conf/nginx/helfertool.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/helfertool.conf
       - /srv/helfertool/conf/helfertool/settings_local.py:/app/helfertool/helfertool/settings_local.py
       - /srv/helfertool/conf/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
       - /srv/helfertool/conf/supervisor:/etc/supervisor/conf.d
       - /srv/helfertool/conf/uwsgi:/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
     depends_on:
       - "helfertool_rabbitmq"
       - "helfertool_db"
     labels:
      - traefik.backend=helfertool
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:XXX
      - traefik.docker.network=frontproxy
      - traefik.port=80
      - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
     networks:
       - frontproxy
       - helfertoolnet

  helfertool_rabbitmq:
     image: rabbitmq:3
     hostname: helfertool_rabbitmq
     container_name: helfertool_rabbitmq
     environment:
       - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=XXX
       - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=XXX
       - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=XXX
     networks:
       - helfertoolnet

  helfertool_db:
     image: postgres
     command: postgres -c listen_addresses='*'
     hostname: helfertool_db
     container_name: helfertool_db
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXX
       - POSTGRES_USER=XXX
     volumes:
       # Persist the data between container invocations
       - postgresVolume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     networks:
       - helfertoolnet
```

## Logs

### traefik log

```
{"BackendAddr":"172.18.0.7:80",
"BackendName":"backend-helfertool",
"BackendURL":   
{"Scheme":"http",
"Opaque":"",
"User":null,
"Host":"172.18.0.7:80",
"Path":"",
"RawPath":"",
"ForceQuery":false,
"RawQuery":"",
"Fragment":""},
"ClientAddr":"141.60.38.168:60979",
"ClientHost":"141.60.38.168",
"ClientPort":"60979",
"ClientUsername":"-"
,"DownstreamContentSize":11,
"DownstreamStatus":502,
"DownstreamStatusLine":"502 Bad Gateway",
"Duration":1074690,
"FrontendName":"Host-register-stupa-fh-rosenheimde-0",
"OriginContentSize":11,
"OriginDuration":855550,
"OriginStatus":502,
"OriginStatusLine":"502 Bad Gateway",
"Overhead":219140,
"RequestAddr":"register.stupa.fh-rosenheim.de",
"RequestContentSize":0,
"RequestCount":27132,
"RequestHost":"register.stupa.fh-rosenheim.de",
"RequestLine":"GET / HTTP/1.1",
"RequestMethod":"GET",
"RequestPath":"/",
"RequestPort":"-",
"RequestProtocol":"HTTP/1.1",
"RetryAttempts":0,
"StartLocal":"2018-05-25T12:55:18.619598232Z",
"StartUTC":"2018-05-25T12:55:18.619598232Z",
"level":"info",
"msg":"",
"request_Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"request_Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate",
"request_Accept-Language":"de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
"request_Cache-Control":"max-age=0",
"request_Connection":"keep-alive",
"request_Cookie":"csrftoken=awELtrVSPImPNZFNph6SYs0eJuAZcjIzX462ykgUip1hQVQagaaKQxZhFUbzUrS5; 
sessionid=4bcrynx0qyu2bam1nf8eewiurv0vtn5a",
"request_Referer":"http://register.stupa.fh-rosenheim.de/weinfest2018/",
"request_Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
"request_User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0","time":"2018-05-25T12:55:18Z"}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I am facing same issue, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the case that your uswgi container restarted and got a new ip address in docker, so nginx couldn't resolve it.